# What is the difference between Shapiro-Francia and Shapiro-Wilk tests of normality?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, normality-assumption, shapiro-wilk-test

I apologize for this easy/basic question. Please forgive me if this is a duplicate question.

I've been researching the Shapiro-Wilk test (1965) of normality for a project. In doing so, I found an article by Royston (1982), which allows for a sample size up to n=2000 (providing a way to calculate p-values up to n=2000).

Further research has now lead me to Shapiro-Francia (1972), which reads exactly like Royston's Extension. (I guess it read to me exactly like Royston's Extension.)

Can someone please explain the difference between the Shapiro-Wilk and Shapiro-Francia tests of Normality?

**References**
Royston, J. P. (1982). [An extension of Shapiro and Wilk's W test for normality to large samples](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2347973.pdf). *Applied Statistics*, 115-124.

Shapiro, S. S. and Francia, R. S. (1972). [An approximate analysis of variance test for normality](http://sci-hub.tw/). *Journal of the American Statistical Association*, 67(1):215–216.

Shapiro, S. S. and Wilk, M. B. (1965). [An analysis of variance test for normality (complete samples)](http://www.math.utah.edu/~morris/Courses/ShapiroWilk.pdf). *Biometrika*, 52(3 and 4):591–611.

Comment: Can someone please add the tags: "Shapiro-Wilks" or "Shapiro-Francia"? Or "Test-for-Normality"?

Comment: These are tests *of* not tests *for* normality: the null hypothesis is that the data are normally distributed. The tests provide evidence/fail to provide evidence that the data *are not* normally distributed.

Comment: I apologize. The various articles I've been reading refer to the tests both ways: "tests OF Normality" and "tests FOR Normality".

Comment: Frequentist hypothesis tests either reject or fail to reject a null, and they only provide evidence for, or fail to provide evidence for the alternate. And no apology needed! :)